# Is there a git equivalent for Perforce's "Reconcile Offline Work" operation?

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

I was doing a hard reset of one of my branches to a specific commit and interrupted it halfway. While attempting to remove the operation lock by deleting `index.lock`, I accidentally deleted the `index` file of my local git checkout and it caused git to confuse some files as deleted and some others as not yet in the repository.

When I recovered the `index` file from my recycle bin, everything seems to be normal, but I'm worried some things may have been lost track of by git.

Is there a git equivalent for Perforce's "Reconcile Offline Work" operation? Or is `git reset` sufficient and will reliably catch any inconsistencies between the local checkout and the remote?

Comment: I would run `git status` and examine the output carefully.

Comment: I usually have the opposite problem: modern DVCSes (git/bzr/hg) do not need Perforce's "reconcile offline work", since they normally do that all the time (in the local repo/clone/checkout).   --- Safest thing would probably be to just do a new git clone.  --- Are you worried that re-cloning would be too slow?  Or do you have state in the local repo that you have not pushed to any remote repo?  ---  If neither of these two obstacles, I think you have not the git mindset - "clones are cheap (or at least should be)".

Answer (score 0):

Try `git add -A`

This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.